# Passing dynamic id and url to ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to pass dynamic id and ur to ajax call. I have created a basic div structure and want to load data in that same structure from different url and also want that div to replicate itself with different id so that multiple divs with same structure but different data and ids can be shown.I have written a code for that but unfortunately it is showing data from different url in same div and other divs are showing empty data.I am uploading a code snippet but in that i am only able to provide static id.

```
$(function(){   
var camera, renderer;
var mpi=Math.PI /180;
var circleRadius = 1800;
var startAngle = 0;
var centerX = 0;
var centerZ = 0;
var startRadians = startAngle + mpi;
var totalSpheres = 5;
var incrementAngle = 360/totalSpheres;
var incrementRadians = incrementAngle * mpi;
var Element = function ( id, w, h, position, rotation ) {
                    var html = [
                            '<div class="wrapper" >',
                            '<ul class="stage clearfix">',
                            '<li class="scene" >',
                             '<div class="movie i1" id="' + id + '" >',


                             '</div>',
                             '</li>',



                             '</ul>',
                             '</div>'
                        ].join('\n');
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    $(div).html(html);


                    var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( div );
                    object.position.x = position.x;
                    object.position.y = position.y;
                    object.position.z = position.z;
                    object.rotation.x = rotation.x;
                    object.rotation.y = rotation.y;
                    object.rotation.z = rotation.z;
                    return object;

                    }           
        init();
        function init() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
            var renderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight*.85);
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10 );
            camera.position.set(-100,60,4000);
            var group = new THREE.Group();

            var str = {
                "0":"attacker",
                "1":"defender",

            }
            for ( var i = 0; i < totalSpheres; i ++ ) {
            $.ajax({
    dataType: "text",
    url: "http://localhost/liberate/threeee/PAGES/Information/content.html",
    success: function (data) {      
                console.log(data);
        $(str[i]).append(data)
    }});
            }

            for ( var i = 0; i < totalSpheres; i ++ ) {
                var xp = centerX + Math.sin(startRadians) * circleRadius;
                var zp = centerZ + Math.cos(startRadians) * circleRadius;
                group.add( new Element( str, 1000, 1000, new THREE.Vector3(xp, 0, zp), new THREE.Vector3(0, i*incrementAngle * (Math.PI/180.0), 0) ) );
                startRadians += incrementRadians;


              }
                scene.add(group);


            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

});
```

I have tried dynamic id and tried to debug the code but it is showing Object object in the id.Can someone give any suggestion of what can be done in this case.

Comment: You send nothing through ajax.

Comment: But if i send nothing then how can i see the data in the console

Comment: You're passing `str` as id, which is an object. Instead you might want to pass just `i` (I'm not sure what you want to use the id for).

Comment: Tried not working. What if instead of "0" : http://..." i supply dynamic id like id="http://..... ".

Answer (score 0):

my guess, you are trying to iterate loop using totalSpheres & its value is 5.

```
var totalSpheres = 5;
```

when you do str[i], it will work for first 2 iteration since you have only 2 objects inside the str.

please check that.

Comment: I get that but  2 iteration is just a example thats not a issue